# Referencing theorems in HTML like you can with LaTeX

Tags: html, css, counter

I am writing some webpages containing math content (using MathJax), and I am looking for a way to do the equivalent of the LaTeX theorem referencing, as in the following example:

```latex
\begin{theorem} \label{thm:commute}
    a+b=b+a
\end{theorem} 
According to Theorem (\ref{thm:commute}), $2+3=3+2$.
```

I am using the following CSS/HTML code to produce automatic theorem numbering:

```css
.theorem:before {
    font-style: normal; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    content: "Theorem " counter(chap)"."counter(sect)"."counter(thm)" ";  
}
.theorem {
    counter-increment: theorem ;  
}
```

```html
<div class="theorem">     
    \(a+b=b+a\)
</div>
```

I need the equivalent of the LaTeX `\label`, and `\ref` commands to assign a name to a theorem so that it can be referenced later on the webpage, and that will display `counter(chap)"."counter(sect)"."counter(thm)`.