# Implementing a "Named Theorem" environment in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

In mathematical documents you often see historically important or named theorems distinguished from the rest of the theorems in the document.

[image: Two theorems screenshotted from a paper]

Now I have numbered theorems implemented:

```css
body {
  counter-reset: theorem;
}
p.theorem {
  display: block; 
}
p.theorem::before {
  counter-increment: theorem; 
  content: "Theorem " counter(theorem) " \2014 "; 
}
```

So the above can *almost* be created with:

```html
<p class="theorem">
  This is your typical theorem, probably proved by the author of 
  the current paper, and doesn't need any special decoration.
</p> 
<p class="theorem">
  This theorem is important enough to warrant attribution to its author and a 
  reference to the entry in the bibliography where the author proves this theorem.
</p>
```

But how can one implement this naming/attribution of a theorem on a webpage? Naively one would have to pass some parameter, the `name`, to the tag you're using for the theorem, but I don't think that's possible just with HTML/CSS. If this is possible, it would be nice if it's possible that the `name` be a hyperlink too, to link to the referenced work.

Also see this related question about [referencing theorems like you can do with LaTeX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49520365/2671341).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference the content of an element's attributes from within the CSS `content` property using `attr()`

```css
body {
  counter-reset: theorem;
}
p.theorem::before {
  counter-increment: theorem; 
  content: "Theorem " counter(theorem) " \2014 "; 
}
p.theorem[data-attribution]::before {
  content: "Theorem " counter(theorem) " (" attr(data-attribution) ")  \2014 ";
}
```

```html
<p class="theorem">This is your typical theorem, probably proved by the author of the current paper, and doesn't need any special decoration.</p>
<p class="theorem" data-attribution="Noether">This theorem is important enough to warrant attribution to its author and a reference to the entry in the bibliography where the author proves this theorem.</p>
```

Here's a good article on it: https://davidwalsh.name/css-content-attr

However, you won't be able to make it an accessible link without adding some javascript to the mix. At that point, it may be worth just using semantic HTML to markup the content from the get-go—which is bound to be more accessible—using a pattern like:

```css
.theorem {
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}
.theorem figcaption::after {
    content: " \2014 "
}
.theorem figcaption,
.theorem p {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
<figure class="theorem">
    <figcaption>Theorem 1</figcaption>
    <p>This is your typical theorem, probably proved by the author of the current paper, and doesn't need any special decoration.</p>
</figure>
<figure class="theorem">
    <figcaption>Theorem 2 (Noether [<a href="#">1</a>])</figcaption>
    <p>This theorem is important enough to warrant attribution to its author and a reference to the entry in the bibliography where the author proves this theorem.</p>
</figure>
```

Comment: It's a little disappointing to have to choose between automatic numbering and getting hyperlinks in the attribution. But I'm so glad to learn that this so straightforward with just CSS. This is a great answer. Thank you!