# Theorem numeration acroos diferent pages

Tags: html, css, enumerate

Here [Implementing a "Named Theorem" environment in HTML/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55152190/implementing-a-named-theorem-environment-in-html-css) there is an explanation of how one can enumerate automatically the theorems in a page. For example If I have the file Theorems2.html and I add theorems in the page these will be enumerated from 1 on. Now, If this page is before another in the sense that it exists Theorems1.html and there are theorems enumerated there. If you open Theorems1.html you see theorems from one to n, and when you open Theorems2.html you see theorems from one to m, but it is necessary that when you open Theorems2.html you see theorems from n+1 to p. How can I do this?

Thank you so much gentle people.

So it's how I enumerate theorems and axioms in a html file, but I want this numerations keep through different files

```
div.axiom{
    font-style: italic;
/*Los márgenes para presentar los axiomas*/
    margin-left: 250px;
    margin-right: 250px;
    margin-top: 75px;
    margin-bottom: 75px;
/*Esto es lo uso para la numeración automática de los axiomas*/
    counter-increment: axioma;
}
div.axiom:before{      /*div.algo:before es para lo que está previo a la proposición*/
    content: "Axioma.";
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
/*Esto vendría a ser el complemento a lo que uso para la numeración automatica de axiomas*/
    content: "Axioma " counter(axioma) ".";
}
div.definition{
    font-style: italic;
/*Los márgenes para presentar los axiomas*/
    margin-left: 250px;
    margin-right: 250px;
    margin-top: 75px;
    margin-bottom: 75px;
/*Esto es lo uso para la numeración automática de los axiomas*/
    counter-increment: definición;
}
div.definition:before{      /*div.algo:before es para lo que está previo a la proposición*/
    content: "Definición.";
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
/*Esto vendría a ser el complemento a lo que uso para la numeración automatica de axiomas*/
    content: "Definición " counter(definición) ".";
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code you have tried so far (HTMl,CSS,etc.).

Comment: @avia I have adde what I have, can you help me?

Comment: Thanks. 1) Would also need some HTML code? 2) You should consider posting in the Spanish section of the website (your question will get flagged as Spanish here..) 3) Not sure what exactly you wan to achieve? Maybe we could chat together I also speak Spanish. Add me on G Chat if you want laurentchevrette **at** gmail **dot** com

Comment: @avia I have sent you a message

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many theorems there are on page 1 you could use `counter-reset: axioma n`. replace n with corresponding number. The counter will start from there.

CSS Syntax

```
    counter-reset: name number|initial|inherit;
```

Property Values
The `name` defines which counter to reset. The `number` sets the value the counter is reset to on each occurrence of the selector. The default number value is 0.